# How do i get my Mac to give me permission to install Yarn and npx in terminal?

Tags: 0x

I've done research on how to get permission but it doesn't seem to work. At first I tried on my mac book pro, but after trying for hours I still couldn't seem to get it to work so I switched to my Mac computer, and its doing the same thing. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a newer M1 Mac, you might need to install Rosetta and homebrew (specifically the version for ARM M1 chips) before you can install yarn.

1. Check if your Mac is using an Apple M1 chip ([instructions](https://www.howtogeek.com/706226/how-to-check-if-your-mac-is-using-an-intel-or-apple-silicon-processor/))
2. If you are using an M1 Mac, install Rosetta 2 and homebrew following [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64997047). Learn more about Rosetta 2 [here](https://support.alfasoft.com/hc/en-us/articles/360017160858-How-to-use-Rosetta-and-what-is-it-M1-chip-).
3. Install yarn via the [homebrew method](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/#mac-stable) (under the Alternatives section)

As for npx, you might also need to check you have the lastest Node version (which should be M1 compatible); older versions probably also need Rosetta ([details](https://justinwride.medium.com/install-node-and-npm-natively-on-apple-silicon-mac-m1-7432c826389b)).